# How to add a thread or any service in background in Android Development?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-notifications

I want to add a technique, which will Check value of a variable after 5 or 10 mins interval. If the value of the variable have Changed then send a notification to notification bar from Application.
&
Application will always work in Background and Foreground.

Any sample code or Tutorial link suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `runOnUiThread` or any simple thread. Use an `AsyncTask` for this. It is very simple: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html